# struts2 s:if tag behaves differently for string and boolean

Tags: jsp, struts2, ognl, struts-tags

I have an `s:iterator` with `s:if` like below

```
<s:iterator var="connections" value="serviceItems">
   <s:if test='disableCheckBox == "Y"'>
      disableCheckBox works
   </s:if>
   <s:if test='#{troubleSupported.equals("true")}'>
     troubleWorks
   </s:if>
</s:iterator>
```

The above code works, but if I change the second if like below, it does not work.

```
<s:if test="troubleSupported=='true'">
<s:if test="troubleSupported.equals('true')">
```

Can someone please explain what could be reason for this difference. Am I doing something wrong here?

The only difference I could see is, the action variable is declared as a `boolean` for troubleSupported and `String` for disableCheckBox (Note: Not directly, but through some intermittent Vectors). Could this affect the outcome like what I am seeing.

P.S: To complicate this a bit further, if I swap the single and double quotes for the working scenario,

`<s:if test="disableCheckBox == 'Y'">` does not work,

but
`<s:if test="#{troubleSupported.equals('true')}">` continues to work.

Currently, I'm not looking at this. I am confused enough with my original issue. :)

Comment: It's not clear which option has worked for you. Also we can't know what is iterated?

Comment: My first code worked. Edited the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<s:if test="troubleSupported=='true'">` is not a correct way to check equality in java, and many more languages. Correct way is : `<s:if test="troubleSupported===true">`. Far better is : `<s:if test="troubleSupported">` because you want to test if your boolean is true, so keep it simple.

You can check boolean values with thymeleaf-like expressions too, but it is more verbose : `<s:if test="#{troubleSupported.equals('true')}">`.

Comment: The expression is basically has wrong syntax in OGNL.

Comment: Yes, that's another way to tell the same thing. Comparing the boolean value as a string value `'true'` is a big mistake too.

Comment: It is not comparing, but throwing exception while parsing.

Comment: Of course yes, in workflow it is validated before any rendering, and because it is wrong written, it will throw an exception.

Comment: @RomanC. Can you please elaborate a bit on the "not comparing, but throwing exception" part. I understand that the problem with my code is the string comparison for a boolean, but the code did seem to work for me. There was no error logs seen. I wish to understand where the code is taking the exception route.

Comment: @KrishnarajV maybe your app exception handler is not handling them, because of log level of your webapp.

Comment: I was able to see some jsp compilation error when I was messing around with this tag trying to figure out what was happening. Not sure how this boolean to String Exception is getting missed out. Thanks for the pointers though. Will try to change logging levels and see.

Comment: It could be this or other things, depending of the rest of your code. You're welcome.

Comment: @KrishnarajV How it seemed to work if the body of the tag never printed due to expression errors?

Comment: The expression errors were only when I was messing around with the tag trying to figure out what was happening. When I used the `<s:if test='#{troubleSupported.equals("true")}'>`, it worked perfectly fine without any errors.